# tikz-3dplot: How to draw small circles of a sphere in a given angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

What is the right method to draw a small circle at a certain angle?

I can only do it improvisational for the right angle.

[image]

Hint: I want to draw such a picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2.6} %  

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
tdplot_main_coords,
%tdplot_rotated_coords,
font=\footnotesize,
Helpcircle/.style={gray!70!black,
%densely dashed
},
]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{0.9*\r} %  
\coordinate[label=$M$] (M) at (0,0,0); 
\coordinate[label=$S$] (S) at (0,0,\h); 

\draw[Helpcircle] (M) circle[radius=\r];

\draw[Helpcircle] ([shift={(0,0,\h)}]M) circle[radius=sqrt(\r^2-\h^2)];

\draw[Helpcircle, rotate=90, red] (0,0,-\h) coordinate[label=$A$] (A) circle[radius=sqrt(\r^2-\h^2)];
\draw[] (M) -- (A);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\teta}{30} %
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-\h*cos(\teta)} %    
\draw[blue] (M) -- ([xshift=\r cm, yshift=\y cm]M);

% Sphere
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
\fill[ball color= gray!20, opacity = 0.25] (M) circle (\r); 
\end{scope}

%% Points
\foreach \P in {M,S, A}{
\shade[ball color=white] (\P) circle (1.75pt);
}

\begin{scope}[-latex, shift={(M)}, xshift=1.5*\r cm, yshift=0.1*\r cm]
\foreach \P/\s/\Pos in {(1,0,0)/x/right, (0,1,0)/y/below, (0,0,1)/z/right} 
\draw[] (0,0,0) -- \P node[\Pos, pos=0.9,inner sep=2pt]{$\s$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The blue line was drawn using screen coordinates (xshift,yshift), as was coordinate (A) [rotate].  You can translate 3D coordinates into screen coordinate, but not the inverse.

Comment: `tikz-3dplot` autoloads the `3d` (and `calc`) libraries. You can switch to specific plane using e.g. `canvas is xz plane at y=1`.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to draw the circle at `(A)` using 3D coordinates, assuming you intended `(A)` to be at `(0,\h,0)`.

Using rotated coordinates can be tricky.  The first angle rotates the XY plane, and has no effect on the Z axis.  The second angle rotates in the (new) XZ plane, and has no effect on the (new) Y axis.  Try to avoid using the third angle, which rotates in the new XY plane, although some transformations can only be done that way; e.g. `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{-90}`.

Note that the transformations are NOT cumulative.

BTW, `\r^2` is computed using `exp(2*log(\r))` which is slow and only works for positive numbers.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2.6} %  

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
tdplot_main_coords,
%tdplot_rotated_coords,
font=\footnotesize,
Helpcircle/.style={gray!70!black,
%densely dashed
},
]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{0.9*\r} %  
\coordinate[label=$M$] (M) at (0,0,0); 
\coordinate[label=$S$] (S) at (0,0,\h); 
\coordinate[label=$A$] (A) at (0,\h,0); 

\draw[Helpcircle] (M) circle[radius=\r];

\draw[Helpcircle] (S) circle[radius=sqrt(\r*\r-\h*\h)];% much faster then ^2

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{0}%
\draw[Helpcircle, red, tdplot_rotated_coords] (A) circle[radius=sqrt(\r*\r-\h*\h)];
\draw[] (M) -- (A);

% Sphere
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
\fill[ball color= gray!20, opacity = 0.25] (M) circle (\r); 
\end{scope}

%% Points
\foreach \P in {M,S, A}{
\shade[ball color=white] (\P) circle (1.75pt);
}

\begin{scope}[-latex, shift={(M)}, xshift=1.5*\r cm, yshift=0.1*\r cm]
\foreach \P/\s/\Pos in {(1,0,0)/x/right, (0,1,0)/y/below, (0,0,1)/z/right} 
\draw[] (0,0,0) -- \P node[\Pos, pos=0.9,inner sep=2pt]{$\s$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]