How to wrap a pattern around a 3d shape?
My question is: in tikzpicture, given a parametrisation φ of a surface in the three-dimensional plane, and a 2d pattern like northwestlines, how do I wrap that pattern around the parametrised shape?

For instance, here is an example φ of a parametrised sphere:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        hide axis,
        view={60}{30},
        z buffer=sort,
    ]
    \addplot3[
        surf,
        shader=flat,
        samples=30,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0:180,
    ]
    ({cos(x)*sin(y)}, {sin(x)*sin(y)}, {cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

How can I add the pattern northwestlines in the way sketched above?
This is a follow up to a previous question, where I asked a different question and got a reasonably good answer, including a very special case of this answer for the square grid pattern only.

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz OK, I've added that, can you remove the downvote if it was you?

As a rule of thumb if your posted code doesn't start with \documentclass it's quite safe to say it won't compile. Non-compiling code will attract negative reactions of any kind, including ignoring questions, i.e. having no answers. // Please try to compile your posted code in a fresh file to learn, what I mean. Thank you

@MS-SPO Added, thanks.

@Pulcinella Thanks for the update. I retracted my close vote.

Maybe the title would be more meaningful without "Cool 19th century pictures part 2: ". That's not really relevant to the problem.

You can turn a circle into an ellipse based on its location on the sphere (angle) provided the edge of the shere doesn't get in the way.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501274/tikz-3dplot-how-to-draw-small-circles-of-a-sphere-in-a-given-angle/501294?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C21.7069#501294

Right, but I'm specifically looking for a technique that will work for an arbitrary "patterns = [bla]" pattern, not just the hexagonal circular blobs pattern.

BTW, topologically, one cannot map a 2D pattern onto a sphere without a point convergence (crown).

it may be easier to use something which has a concept of 3d built-in. pgf/tikz is basically 2d. any 3d effects have to be reduced to 2d i.e. faked. that's in contrast to some other options which accommodate 3d from the ground up.

@cfr I'd definitely be happy with a different solution native to TeX that could do this (and extra happy if it could be incorporated in tikzpicture diagrams).

A line in the north west lines pattern can be described by y=-x+\n where \n is the offset of that line. Plotting a multitude of these lines will create the pattern. Mapping this pattern onto a sphere is the reverse of a map projection and can be done in infinite many ways. See here for a selection:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection
Using your projection ({cos(x)*sin(y)}, {sin(x)*sin(y)}, {cos(y)}) gives this result for circles and lines:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
view={0}{0},
axis equal,
hide axis,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
r=4;
cx=\n+r*cos(t);
cy=\m+10*mod(\n/20,2)+r*sin(t);
}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
domain=0:180, y domain=0:180,
samples=30,
z buffer=sort,
] ({cos(x)*sin(y)}, {sin(x)*sin(y)}, {cos(y)});
\foreach \n in {0,20,...,160}{
\foreach \m in {0,20,...,160}{
  \addplot3[
  domain=0:360, samples=20, variable=t,
  samples y=1,
  smooth,
  fill,
] ({cos(cx)*sin(cy)}, {sin(cx)*sin(cy)}, {cos(cy)});
}}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[xshift=5cm,]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
domain=0:360, y domain=0:180,
samples=30,
z buffer=sort,
] ({cos(x)*sin(y)}, {sin(x)*sin(y)}, {cos(y)});
\foreach \n in {0,5,...,355}{
  \addplot3[
  domain=0:180, samples=30,
  samples y=1,
  smooth,
  ] ({cos(x)*sin(-x+\n)}, {sin(x)*sin(-x+\n)}, {cos(-x+\n)});
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks! This is a really good solution, I like how it gives me the freedom to manually design any pattern.
